# iOS 13 orientation changed forcefully

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, ios13.1.2

I have an app and it's working fine as expected in iOS 12 and below. I am only supporting portrait mode in my app. Now in iOS 13 what happens is If I open camera to capture video and rotates the device camera rotates but when I tap on choose video my app also shows rotated in landscape. Anyone knows anything about this ?

**UPDATE**

The issue appears again but randomly whenever we dismiss a presented view controller. anyone knows anything about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by setting portrait orientation in delegate callbacks of `UIImagePickerController`. The issue was only appearing when we are opening camera directly only with video option. If we open camera with Photo and Video option. It works perfectly fine.

```
- (void)setPortraitOrientation {
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) forKey:@"orientation"];
    [UINavigationController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self setPortraitOrientation];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self setPortraitOrientation];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}
```